# Starting software VIA SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, service

I'm curious as to how you can go about starting software through an SSH tunnel, but keep the software running on the SSH server.

For example, I host a minecraft server for my brother and his friends. If something happens and I need to restart the minecraft software, while I can do it from any computer via Putty or the Terminal, that session of the minecraft software running will only stay alive if I keep the SSH tunnel up.

How can I start software and services using SSH without having the SSH Client host the software sessions?

Comment: This is a question about your hobby and therefore off-topic here. Anyway, read http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server

Comment: Thanks, but that link is actually off topic. I don't care about minecraft, I'm asking a general question about ssh. The minecraft example was just that...an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this example I will use `svnserve` as the daemon process that has to be started. So, assuming your SSH user-name is "kyle" and your server's host-name is "home.example.com", you can execute following:

```
ssh -f kyle@home.example.com "svnserve -d"
```

Sometimes user must force allocation of the pseudo-terminal, in that case use the -t flag:

```
ssh -t kyle@home.example.com "svnserve -d"
```

If your daemon process does not know how to "daemonise" itself, then you can send it to the background:

```
ssh -f kyle@home.example.com "/usr/local/bin/minecraft-server &"
```

Reading SSH manual page is highly recommended... ;) You could find this information yourself if you have spent 2min reading SSH client's manual page.

Comment: Thank you Dejan. I appreciate the answer and will make sure all future questions have more thorough research first.

Answer (score -3):

You should use screen or tmux.

screen   start screen, then you can attach and detach the terminal at will ( ctrl + A , D ) to detach.

Comment: No. Running a server software from inside a screen session might be possible but you want to create a proper service out of it so it get actually started automatically if you need to restart the machine.

Comment: Writing a service is most of the time non trivial to do it right ( some servers do not correctly close all open files, do not write pid file, etc ). This also requires root access and not everybody has it.

Comment: Yes, this is a task for a professional sysadmin, not an amateur. [SF] is for pros only.